# C++: convert TCHAR array to std::string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, char, type-conversion

I want to convert a `TCHAR` array to `std::string`. After searching the internet, I did it by this way:

```
TCHAR fileName[260];
GetProcessName(
    reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(processId), 
    fileName, 
    MAX_PATH
    );
std::wstring tmpWString( fileName );
std::string result( tmpWString.begin(), tmpWString.end() );

std::cout << "the length of the tmpWString is: " << tmpWString.length() << std::endl;
```

This gives me a `tmpWString` of length `0`. However, by a pure coincidence, I added a sleep function before the conversion, then everything goes smoothly, and I can get the conversion result properly:

```
TCHAR fileName[260];
::Sleep(500);
GetProcessName(
    reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(processId), 
    fileName, 
    MAX_PATH
    );
std::wstring tmpWString( fileName );
std::string result( tmpWString.begin(), tmpWString.end() );

std::cout << "the length of the tmpWString is: " << tmpWString.length() << std::endl;
std::cout << "this is the resulted string: " << result << std::endl;
```

I didn't get it. Why would adding a sleep makes it work while omitting it causes a zero-length `wstring`? I didn't want to include any sleep in my code after all. Could someone explain this? My working environment is Visual Studio 2010, on a virtual machine with Windows XP. For the `Character Set` of `Configuration Properties` of VS2010, I didn't specify any set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try couting the result in both examples.

Comment: and show us the "... // add some value to fileName here" part. If you mess things up there, you might end up with undefined behaviour. BTW is your application multithreaded ?

Comment: I updated my question, and yes, this code is multithreaded.

Comment: @Ben: without sleep, couting gives me an empty string, with sleep however, it correctly gives out the process name obtained by the code.

Comment: @E_learner: try to isolate the problem even more. Be systematic, and employ an aggressive trial & error strategy to find the cause of the error. For example, replace variables or macros with fixed values (i.e. literals), one after the other, see if it changes something. Try to run the code in the main thread before multiple threads are running. And so on. If a sleep() changes behaviour the way you describe, then something is seriously messed up and guessing probably won't help much :)